# Defining in-line comments in Python

Tags: python-3.x, comments

Python has three types of comments: full-line comments, in-line comments and multi-line comments.

```
# Prints: "Hello World!"
print("Hello World!")


print("Hello World!") # Prints: "Hello World!"


"""
Prints:
Hello World!
"""
print("Hello World!")
```

Now, if you would define your own comments, it would be easy to use `rstrip()` to ignore a line with an if statement where you check if your line starts with a character of your choice (`||` for this example). But, that checks if a line **starts with** `||`. How would track your line to the point where the comment is placed, and then ignore the rest of the line?

```
|| Right now, only this works.


...    || This doesn't.
```

### **Edit: Came up with a way myself.**

```
line=(line.split("||")[0])
```

Comment: Don't contain your answer in the question, just post your answer.

Comment: @ppwater Sorry, didn't know you could do that. I'm new to stackoverflow, as you can tell.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer:

```
line=(line.split("||")[0])
```

Comment: What if `||` occurs inside a string literal?

Comment: I fail to see how this is related to comments in Python anyway. Also, the third example in your question is not a multiline comment, it's a string.

Comment: @khelwood That's a good statement, I didn't think of that.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Yes, but people use it for comments anyway, and I just used it as example.